# Why does indexOf not work in this js code?

Tags: javascript, function, indexof

Cant for the life of me work out why this is returning undefined?

```
var letter = {
  whereIsTheLetter : function(letter){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    letter = alphabet.indexOf();
  }

};

var a = letter.whereIsTheLetter('x')
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Because you're not returning anything?

Comment: `return alphabet.indexOf(letter);`

Comment: im running node filename.js in the console

Comment: @thedove - Look on the above suggestion, you need to return something from the function.

Comment: ha fair, what a big miss. i'll shoot myself me thinks

Comment: In line 4 you call the function with no args - instead replace with `return alphabet.indexOf(letter)`

Comment: I think it's a shame that people even post answers on these kind of questions, a comment will do then perhaps the OP could actually learn something.

Comment: However much negative reputation I get for not using "comments" for a decent answer, I will continue to write answers to help OP.

Comment: @CharlieH - Do that if you don't want the OP to learn anything for himself. I would argue that a comment on these kind of really basic question is a very much nicer approach. Especially since the answer are all ready there.

Comment: Why do you think the OP has to learn it from another answer than this one? He can land on some other answer - he can land on this one - whats the difference if he learns it from somewhere? Besides when you say "you have to return something" or showing it by example - its pretty much the same. No magic happens in either way.

Answer (score -1):

Your function need to return something. Also you should supply an argument to `indexOf` method.

```
whereIsTheLetter : function(letter){
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    return alphabet.indexOf(letter);
  }
```